# Changing the max extent of a view after initialization in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I want to be able to dynamically change the maximum extents of my OpenLayers map after initialization.

The use case is, users can change their base map, and some of these base maps cover the whole world, some only part of it, so if they switch to a map that only covers Great Britain, I want the view to be constrained to those bounds. When they switch back to a global map, it can be unconstrained again.

I have managed to get it to work using code like the below, but it involves setting a brand new view based on my existing view every time, and it just doesn't seem particularly clever. I could also run into problems if I have more view parameters as I'd always have to remember to update this code to include them.

```
let map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-2.3314, 50.7621]),
      zoom: 9
    })
  });

let extentSwitch = document.getElementById('extentSwitch');
let dorsetExtent = [-334421, 6532667, -180630, 6637844];

extentSwitch.addEventListener('click',e => {

    if(extentSwitch.dataset.currentExtent === 'global'){
        map.setView(new ol.View({
          center: map.getView().getCenter(),
          zoom: map.getView().getZoom(),
            extent: dorsetExtent
      }));

      extentSwitch.dataset.currentExtent = 'dorset';
      extentSwitch.innerText = 'Switch back to global extent';
      }else{
        map.setView(new ol.View({
          center: map.getView().getCenter(),
          zoom: map.getView().getZoom()
      }));
      extentSwitch.dataset.currentExtent = 'global';
      extentSwitch.innerText = 'Switch extent to Dorset only';
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydvsrmpx/6/)

Is this the best way to do what I want? I thought there would be something like `map.getView().setExtent(extent)` but there doesn't seem to be?

Comment: That is the only way to do it using API methods.  The view state consists of center, resolution and rotation, so unless you have disabled rotation you should also include the rotation of the old view.

Comment: @Mike Good point, that would be jarring! Glad I wasn't missing something as well, thanks!